# TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined of balanceTransactions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to display the balance from a Stripe customer or Connect account, but am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined`. The user has just one charge on their account, and it still throws error that it is undefined.

I am likely just misunderstanding the API, but there are not any examples I can find when trying to do this. How do I simply display all balance transactions for a given customer?

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { injectStripe } from 'react-stripe-elements';

class Balance extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        if (this.props.stripe) {
            this.props.stripe.balanceTransactions.list({ limit: 3 }, function(error, transactions) {
                if(error){
                    console.error(error)
                } else {
                    console.log(transactions)
                }

            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Display Balance here
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default injectStripe(Balance);
```

Comment: How are you using the `Balance` component? or rather, how are you passing the stripe param to it?

Comment: @Sreeram my understanding is `injectStripe` from `react-stripe-elements` passes the `stripe` param to the component

Comment: Will need a minimal reproducible example I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm afraid you're using a wrong library. Stripe elements is a client side library for constructing custom forms and collecting card data.

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov so the `stripe` param is not being explicitly passed to the component by `injectStripe`?

Comment: Stripe has different APIs for different actions. You're Stripe param probably doesn't have `balanceTransactions ` property. It's probably from serverside Stripe Node.JS library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from react-stripe-elements readme:

Within an injected component, you can call any of the following:

```
this.props.stripe.createPaymentMethod
this.props.stripe.createToken
this.props.stripe.createSource
this.props.stripe.handleCardPayment
```

So you're using a wrong library.

The correct library is [stripe-node](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node)

Comment: This solves a couple of my other issues, thanks for clarifying my understanding!!

Answer (score 1):

To remove the error, you should do a check in `stripe.balanceTransactions`.

```
componentDidMount(){
    if (this.props.stripe && this.props.stripe.balanceTransactions) {
        this.props.stripe.balanceTransactions.list({ limit: 3 }, function(error, transactions) {
            if(error){
                console.error(error)
            } else {
                console.log(transactions)
            }

        });
    }
}
```

And also, if you take a look in the [documentation](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements#setting-up-your-payment-form-injectstripe), `injectStripe` doesn't give `stripe.balanceTransactions` prop.

These are the only methods you can call

- `this.props.stripe.createPaymentMethod`
- `this.props.stripe.createToken`
- `this.props.stripe.createSource`
- `this.props.stripe.handleCardPayment`

Comment: Not throwing an error anymore, but is never going inside the if() statement to list the transactions